# How to configure various client applications to display AVL data?

Tags: gps, cad, nmea

Given x number of GPS units transmitting NMEA formatted strings back to a server (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx) is there a way to listen in on the traffic and parse NMEA formatted strings for display on a map? Could a combination of a COM port data emulator and the standard tools in the ArcMap GPS toolbar on a client machine get me there? Any thoughts generally (or specifically in regard to ArcGIS) on what I might do (if anything) if I know where the data is coming in?